# How to check the status of the biometric sensor without raising the authorization menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to find out if biometrics is blocked before it is raised.
In the android documentation there is a method `biometricManager.canAuthenticate();`

It returns:

```
BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE
BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE
BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED
BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE
BIOMETRIC_ERROR_SECURITY_UPDATE_REQUIRED
BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS
```

And there is no information about the sensor locking, but if suddenly the sensor is locked then when trying to raise biometrics - `biometricPrompt.authenticate(...)` we will get errors `ERROR_LOCKOUT` or `ERROR_LOCKOUT_PERMANENT`

**Question - is there a way to check the status of the sensor before the biometrics are raised?**

Comment: classical google api. the best fix is to use some 3rd party lib i believe

Answer (score 0):

Here the possible solution:

```
override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {

  //Sensor locked for 30 seconds
  //Store timestamp when lockuot happens and check for 30 seconds timeout
  BiometricCodes.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_LOCKOUT -> {
    BiometricStorage.storeLockoutTs() 
  }
  //Sensor locked permanently
  //Device lock/unlock OR device restart required
  BiometricCodes.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_LOCKOUT_PERMANENT -> {
    BiometricStorage.setBiometricSensorPermanentlyLocked()
  }
}
}
```

Also, you need to register BroadcastReceiver for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` and/or `android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT`.

When the device is booted or unlocked, this receiver should catch the event and you must reset the `BiometricSensorPermanentlyLocked` state.

See the example here:
https://github.com/Salat-Cx65/AdvancedBiometricPromptCompat/blob/main/biometric/src/main/java/dev/skomlach/biometric/compat/utils/DeviceUnlockedReceiver.kt